# How to return a string as a CSV with proper encoding for Excel

Tags: asp.net-core, encoding, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<FileResult>> GetCSV()
{
    var stringCsv = await _statistics.GetUserCSV();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        sw.Write(stringCsv);
        sw.Flush();
        return File(stream.ToArray(), "text/csv", "thefile.csv");
    }
}
```

If I inspect stringCsv  while debugging it looks good, but If I look at the resulting CSV in Excel I get this.

[image]

The missing letters are the Swedish letters ÅÄÖ.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not coming from your code. It is from the file itself. Try the following:

- On a Windows computer, open the CSV file using Notepad.
  Click "File > Save As".
- In the dialog window that appears - select "ANSI" from the "Encoding" field. Then click "Save".
- That's all! Open this new CSV file using Excel - your non-English characters should be displayed properly.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: 1. You can omit the intermediate step with Notepad using `iso-8859-1` or `windows-1252` instead of `UTF8` while defining `var sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.…)`. 2. Alternatively (and maybe better), force the `UTF8` encoding while importing a `csv` file into Excel (or configure Excel to open `UTF8` by default - if it's possible?)